# What are white numbers at grandmasters icons in char select?

Tags: overwatch

What are these white numbers at grandmaster icons in char select? [image]
I belive they should be connected with their place on ladder, but **what exactly are they?** Their place? Their place among the same hero players? Something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These numbers refer to the position that player is in the **Top 500** in their respective region

This number is irrespective of their hero of choice, and is region-wide. In addition you can check this in the leaderboards when right clicking the competitive search button.

In the leaderboard view you can check out the 3 most played heroes for each player in the top 500 for each region, as well as their SR.